# Lorentz boost matrix in terms of four-velocity

Tags: speed-of-light, spacetime, linear-algebra, special-relativity

As I understand it, the value of a 4-vector $x$ in another reference frame ($x'$) with the same orientation can be derived using the Lorentz boost matrix $\bf{\lambda}$ by $x'=\lambda x$. More explicitly,
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x'_0\\
x'_1\\
x'_2\\
x'_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda_{00}&\lambda_{01}&\lambda_{02}&\lambda_{03}\\
\lambda_{10}&\lambda_{11}&\lambda_{12}&\lambda_{13}\\
\lambda_{20}&\lambda_{21}&\lambda_{22}&\lambda_{23}\\
\lambda_{30}&\lambda_{31}&\lambda_{32}&\lambda_{33}\\
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_0\\
x_1\\
x_2\\
x_3\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
I have seen examples of these components written in terms of $\beta$ and $\gamma$, which are defined as
$$\beta=\frac{v}{c}$$
$$\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta\cdot\beta}}$$
where $v$ is the 3-velocity and $c$ is the speed of light. My question is this: How can the components of $\lambda$ be written in terms of the 4-velocity $U$ alone?

I know that $U_0=\gamma c$ and $U_i=\gamma v_i=\gamma c\beta_i$ for $i\in\{1,2,3\}$, but I'm having trouble deriving the components for $\lambda$ using the matrices based on $\beta$ and $\gamma$. An example of one of these matrices [can be found at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_transformation#Matrix_forms). How can I rewrite this matrix in terms of $U$ alone?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. $U = \gamma c (e_t + \vec \beta)$.  You substitute the appropriate components of $U$ in for $\beta, \gamma$, and the result follows.  Is this substitution step where you're having trouble?

Comment: Sorry for asking, but what do you mean by $e_t$?

Comment: The unit vector in the time direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take units $c=1$.

You have $U_0^2-\vec U^2=1$, that is $\gamma^2(1-\beta^2)=1$. With some basic transformations, you will get : $\frac{\gamma - 1}{\beta^2}= \frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma + 1}$

Now, from your Wikipedia matrix, you have obvious term, $ U_0 =\gamma , U_i =\gamma \beta_i$

You have $(\gamma -1) \frac{\beta_i\beta_j}{\beta^2} = \frac{\gamma^2}{\gamma + 1}\beta_i\beta_j = \frac{U_i U_j}{U_0 + 1}$

Finally, $1 + (\gamma -1) \frac{\beta_i^2}{\beta^2} = 1 + \frac{U_i^2}{U_0 + 1}$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could the entire matrix be written in the form $$I+\frac{UU^T}{U_0+c}$$ including the time components?

Comment: @user1667423 : This works only for the spatial part of the matrix, but it does not work for the entire matrix, you can check this with elements $M_{Oi}$ of the matrix which are not equal to $\delta_{0i} + \frac{U_0U_i}{U_0 +1}$

Comment: Of course, I suppose those components can be written as $$\Lambda_{0i}=\Lambda_{i0}=-\frac{U_i}{c}$$ and $$\Lambda_{00}=\frac{U_0}{c}$$?

Comment: Yes, obviously.